# Using GPGME in Debian for C++ Application

Tags: c++, cmake, gpgme

I would like to use GPGME for key generation and encryption in my C++ application. However, while trying to get started, I got stuck with a problems:

I dowloaded the dev package for my debian system. Now I would like to tell my compiler (gcc in Qt Creator) where to find the library with cmake using the [tool mentioned in the documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Building-the-Source.html#Building-the-Source). But I don't know how to add `gpgme-config --cflags --libs` to my compiler flags. This didn't work:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} `gpgme-config --cflags --libs` ")
```

When I try to build the app the compiler can't find `gpgme-config`:

```
c++: error: $(gpgme-config: File or Directory not found
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--cflags’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--libs)’
```

Anyway executing `gpgme-config --cflags --libs` on command line DOES give me a result:

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgpgme -lassuan -lgpg-error
```

I know the documentation also mentions Automake and libtool to make this process easier. But I neither used Automake or libtool before.

---

**UPDATE:**

I also tried to use a FindGpgme.cmake file for GPGME. But the [first file](https://github.com/licq-im/licq/blob/master/licq/cmake/Modules/FindGpgme.cmake) I used required several other cmake files, which I also downloaded. I put them in the same directory as FindGpgme.cmake. The main cmake file (FindGpgme.cmake) was found, but MacroEnsureVersion and MacroBoolTo01 not. My change to my CMakeLists.txt was the following:

```
include(cmake_modules/FindGpgme.cmake)
find_package(Gpgme)
```

I tried relative and absolute path to the other files in FindGpgme.cmake. Same problem - cmake can't find them. My second try was with the [file I found on gitweb](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/proj/kde.git/plain/kde-apps/kdepim/files/FindGpgme.cmake?id=d042684fc50129848dff1ab8c75890e2c425b57e). The error was:

```
CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindGpgme.cmake:376 (set_package_properties):
  Unknown CMake command "set_package_properties".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (include)
```

I have absolutely no glue how to fix that `set_package_properties` problem.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I added

```
include(FeatureSummary)
```

to my CMakeLists.txt as proposed by kfunk. Now I get the following error:

> CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):   By not providing
>   "FindGpgme.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has  asked CMake
>   to find a package configuration file provided by "Gpgme", but   CMake
>   did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Gpgme" with
>   any of   the following names:
>
> ```
> GpgmeConfig.cmake
> gpgme-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "Gpgme" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>   "Gpgme_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>   "Gpgme"   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
>   has been   installed.

Even the message description seams pretty detailed I don't know how to add the FindGpgme.cmake to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` or how to add the requested prefix to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. The dev package however is definitely installed (using package manager)

Comment: To get `set_package_properties` you need to `include(FeatureSummary)` -- it's a standard CMake module.

Comment: `include(cmake_modules/FindGpgme.cmake)` is wrong, don't do that. Please refer to https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries#Using_external_libraries_that_CMake_doesn.27t_yet_have_modules_for -- you need to amend `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the job and solved "problem 1"! Because the post was really long after the progress I decided to put the second problem in a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614154/multiple-definition-while-using-gpgme-in-c-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a proper CMake find script to look up the GPGME installation:

Example here:
  https://quickgit.kde.org/?p=kwallet.git&a=blob&h=7a092104ba0604b0606c4662750b8b32c5c3e2c6&f=cmake%2FFindGpgme.cmake&o=plain

Then something like this in your CMake code (untested):

```
find_package(Gpgme)
include_directories(${GPGME_INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(YOURTARGET ${GPGME_VANILLA_LIBRARIES)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to a proper working FindGpgme.cmake File in plain text? I already tried some FindGpgme Files. But it didn't worked. See my updated answer.

Comment: See my version of FindGpgme.cmake. Afaics it doesn't have extra dependencies.

Comment: But it is not a plaintext file...  or maybe I can't see the link to the plaintext.

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, indeed. Fixed.

Comment: I updated my original post. The problem is the same with your FindGpgme file.