# Unexpected Struct while using GPGME in C++ Application

Tags: c++, gpgme

I would like to use GPGME for key generation and encryption in my C++ application. However, while trying to get started, I got stuck with a problem:

I dowloaded the dev package for my debian system. I told my compiler [how to find the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612409/using-gpgme-in-debian-for-c-application). Just to see if I 'm able to initialize the library ([mentioned here](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/Library-Version-Check.html#Library-Version-Check)) I try to execute the following code..:

```
//--- Main.cpp---

#include <locale.h>
#include <gpgme.h> 

int main(){
       /* Initialize the locale environment.  */
  setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
  gpgme_check_version (NULL);
  gpgme_set_locale (NULL, LC_CTYPE, setlocale (LC_CTYPE, NULL));
#ifdef LC_MESSAGES
  gpgme_set_locale (NULL, LC_MESSAGES, setlocale (LC_MESSAGES, NULL));
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

the line

```
gpgme_set_locale (NULL, LC_CTYPE, setlocale (LC_CTYPE, NULL));
```

is underlined in red by qt creator. The message is

> expected token ';' got 'struct'

But why?

---

**JFYI**

As a synopsys of my [earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612409/using-gpgme-in-debian-for-c-application), my CMakeLists look like this:

*My main CMakeLists.txt in the root directory of my project:*

```
//...
include(FeatureSummary)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
find_package(Gpgme)

# Additional include directories
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}                  
                    ${GPGME_INCLUDES}
)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/application/framework/impl)
```

*And the CMakeLists.txt in application/framework/impl subdirectory:*

```
# Define name of component
SET(COMPONENT_NAME framework)

# Define set of source files for library
SET(comp_src
      //... well, the sources
)

add_executable(${COMPONENT_NAME} ${comp_src})
target_link_libraries(${COMPONENT_NAME} ${GPGME_VANILLA_LIBRARIES})
```

---

**UPDATE**

If I uncommend the line

```
//gpgme_check_version (NULL);
```

the message disappears. I checked the documentation. The signature of the method seams to be valid. Might there be something wrong with the library version I'm using?

---

**EDIT:**

This is not a compiler error, but just a red mark given by the qt creator. I would assume it should be caused by a typo or something. But I can't see any typo. Moreover the application does compile and run even if I didn't comment out the `check_version` line.

Comment: "The application only consists of the GpgmeTest.cpp and a main.cpp (which includes GpgmeTest)." -- so main.cpp includes GpgmeTest.cpp? That's obviously wrong. Please first try to understand the basics of headers and sources: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/

Comment: I know the difference between header and source files and how to use them. But the whole application only consists of about 15 lines of code. I copy pasted the init code in the main and edited my question.

Comment: Do you need a separate function at all or can you move the code to `main()`? There are two function calls there, which of the two calls causes the compiler error? What if you store the parameters in temporaries first? I'm sure a header is missing, and if you had taken the time to produce a minimal example, you would have come to the same conclusion.

Comment: gpgme_check_version causes the error. I updated my question. Also I tried to move the code to the main function. The error is the same. "Expected token ';' got 'struct' "

Comment: Please post full compiler error output (*with* line + column information). And please try to invest some time understanding and resolving issues yourself first.

Comment: @kfunk It is not really a compiler error. It is just a 'highlighting' or mark in my qt creator which gives me the mentioned output if i hover over the mark. I tested the example [provided on this page](http://www.nico.schottelius.org/docs/a-small-introduction-for-using-gpgme/). It compiles and runs fine. Well it doesn't give any output for the keys. But I didn't generated any key before, so I guess this is ok. However the red mark also appears in this example.